# update query date function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I create update query for one table. I need created date from the old database. But I don't know how to do it?

My query is,

```
select 'update organizations set createddate='+CAST(RegisteredDate as varchar(50))+'''where Id='+cast(organizationid as varchar(50))+'' from OrganizationRegisteredDetails
```

when i use this query **my result is**,

```
update organizations set createddate=Aug 19 2009 10:20AM'where Id=1
```

But I want the **result**,

`createddate = 8/19/2009` only. I don't want time.

So how to do this?

Is this possible?

Comment: What type of the `RegisteredDate` and `createddate` fields?

Comment: **RTFM!** [Here's an **extensive** list of all `CAST` styles available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - pick the one most suitable to you! I would recommend using the **ISO-8601** format (style 112) since it's the only reliable one that works for all regional/language settings in SQL Server

Comment: If the two fields are of the same data type `date` or `datetime` then you didn't need any conversion, dates are not stored in a specific format.\

Comment: both are datetime only.But i want without time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to add a single quote before the value,

```
select 'update organizations set createddate='''
                                             ^^ here
```

and use `CAST(RegisteredDate AS DATE)` if you only want the date.

Comment: I have an error like"The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator"

Comment: is `RegisteredDate` a date or a string?

Comment: what is the format? is it `Aug 19 2009 10:20AM`?

Comment: In database, this is the format 2009-08-19 10:20:00. when i used my query below what i add my question i got Aug 19 2009 10:20AM. But I want date type only.

Comment: how about `convert(varchar(15), RegisteredDate, 101)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28082/discussion-between-angdei-and-j-w)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date to the appropriate format.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for date only

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

Comment: I would use style no. 112 (the ISO style) since it's the only one that will reliably work regardless of any regional, language or dateformat settings on your SQL Server

Comment: thanks @marc_s for the focus. will consider that for sure